# Jquery option not selected not working

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, html-select

I have a select menu that acts as a navigation to different absolutely positioned divs. whichever option is shown, that div fades into view via the added class having opacity equal to 1. I can get the divs to add the class based on the menu, but I can't seem to remove that 'active' class if the option is not selected- my JS is as follows:

$("#hine").change(function() {

```
  var who=$('#hine option:not(:selected)').val();
  var whon=$('#hine option:selected').val();

    $(who).removeClass('active');
   $(whon).addClass('active');
```

});

I have a jsfiddle setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/nwT9c/4/

Comment: It seems like you posted the wrong jsfiddle URL...

Comment: sorry- forgot to update-http://jsfiddle.net/nwT9c/5/

Comment: OK, in the current version you are trying to add a class to the selected value (it's a string, not an HTML object) - that doesn't  make sence. More over, why would you want to add a class to the "option" object. You probably want to add it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var whon = $('#hine option:selected').val();
$('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
$(whon).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/nwT9c/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value of the not selected elements to the who variable.

Change to :

```
var who=$('#hine option:not(:selected)');
var whon=$('#hine option:selected');
```

and you should be good

Comment: but i want 'who' to be the not selected ones...because i am removing the active class from the not selected ones...  http://jsfiddle.net/nwT9c/5/

Comment: @lancesmith I see what you are doing now the values are selectors. is $('#hine option:not(:selected)'); returning anything in devtools/firefox console.